# Gmock how to mock a one line function which doesn't take parameters?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

So I have a class which is calling method from other class, but eventually it will return a string or so

This is my class: **Person.cpp**

```cpp
Person::Person(){}
std::string Person::getName(void) {
    return namespaceX::namespaceY::StringVal;
}
```

This is my mock / test class:

```cpp
class MockPerson : public Person{
public:
    typedef ::testing::StrictMock<Person> Strict;
    MockPerson() : Person(){}
    ~MockPerson() override = default;

    MOCK_METHOD0(getName, std::string ());
    std::string callFunc(){
        return Person::getName();
}
```

This is my test header file:

```cpp
class PersonTest : public testing::Test {
public:
    PersonTest () :
            mock(std::make_shared<MockPerson ::Strict>()){}
    ~PersonTest (void) override = default;

    std::shared_ptr<MockPerson ::Strict> mock;
};
```

This is my test:

```cpp
#include "testHeader.hpp"
TEST_F(PersonTest , case1)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*mock, getName());
    ASSERT_EQ(someString, mock->callFunc());
}
```

The test setup looks good to me however when I ran the test, it gives me:

```
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(*mock, getName())...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

And the values return in the ASSERT statement is just the **default value** of the string ("").

Is there a way to go through it? I saw online that we should pass in an actual object to the function but in this case a very simple function causes more troubles than complex ones. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, compiling your example with g++ gives me the following error:

```
error: 'using element_type = class testing::StrictMock<Person>' {aka 'class testing::StrictMock<Person>'} has no member named 'gmock_getName'
```

This can be fixed by passing `MockPerson` as the template parameter for `StrictMock`, instead of passing `Person`:

```
 typedef ::testing::StrictMock<MockPerson> Strict;
```

Second, your declaration of `callFunc` explicitly calls the `getName` function of the `Person` class. This bypasses the mocked version of `getName` and hence the instrumentation that Google Mock inserts to keep track of the number of function calls. Therefore, you get the assertion failure about the function call count mismatch. This can be fixed by making `callFunc` call the `getName` of the current class (`MockPerson`) instead:

```
  std::string callFunc() { return getName(); }
```

Third, the mocked `getName` will return a default-constructed `std::string`, hence you get the `""`. You can change the behavior for all tests belonging to `PersonTest`, by adding this declaration in the `PersonTest` constructor:

```
ON_CALL(*mock, getName()).WillByDefault(Return("xyz"));
```

Or you can set the behavior for individual tests by modifying the `EXPECT_CALL` declarations to:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mock, getName()).WillRepeatedly(Return("xyz"));
```

For both variants, the assert for your `callFunc` should then work as expected:

```
ASSERT_EQ("xyz", mock->callFunc());
```